# Error 0 after moving Joomla site to subfolder

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration, configuration, server-configuration

As told in the title, I just moved my 3.9 Joomla site to a subfolder on my apache server.
Unfortunately when I'm trying to access it, I get this error
"syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file"

I also get some possibilities on why this error may occur :

```
  expired bookmark/favorite
  A search engine has an outdated listing for this site
  an incorrect address
  You do not have access to this page
  The requested resource was not found
```

I'm pretty lost here, am I missing something in the configuration.php fil ? should the htaccess be updated ?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Edit :

Ok, so after deleting the subfolder content and moving the site again but this time directly from the root of the server to the subfolder (first time I downloaded the site to my computer then uploaded it to the subfolder) It works just fine.
So It was definitely a permissions thing as my system changed them on my first attempt.

Comment: As you have answered/fixed your own issue it would be good to have your solution posted as the answer, rather than an edit of the Question, so this can be closed and people can easily see it has been resolved. You might even get a few up-votes if it helps others.